# Dynamically adding rows with dojo combobox (version 1.8.1) as one of the element of row using jQuery (1.8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, html-table

I am trying to insert rows dynamically using jQuery. It is working fine with the following code except that combobox is not appearing in the rows. I have parsed the combobox but still it is not coming and showing me "Design Abbr  [Widget dijit.form.ComboBox, solutionAbbr1]" in the row. Actually I am expecting an combobox here. Can anybody give me some help to fix this issue. I am using 1.8 version for both jquery and dojo.

```
 var maxcount = 0;
 require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/dom", "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dojo/domReady!"],
 function(parser, dom, Memory, ComboBox){
        this.addBlock =  function() {
        maxcount += 1;
        var stateStore = new Memory({data: [{name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
{name:"Alaska", id:"AK"},{name:"Armed Forces the Americas", id:"AA"},
{name:"California", id:"CA"},{name:"Connecticut", id:"CT"}]});
        var comboBoxId = "solutionAbbr"+maxcount;
        var comboBox = new ComboBox({id: comboBoxId, name: "solutionAbbr",
value: "California",store: stateStore,searchAttr: "name"}, "stateSelect");
        //parser.parse.then(function(comboBox) {document.getElementById("solutionAbbr"+maxcount)});
        parser.parse(dijit.byId(comboBoxId));
        //alert(dijit.byId(comboBoxId).get('value'));


    $('<tr id="idForNewRow'+maxcount+'">'
        +'<td colspan="4">'
            +'<table id="idForBorder">'
                +'<tr class="even">'
                    +'<th align="left"><font color="red">Design Abbr</font></th>'
                    +'<td align="left" valign="bottom" colspan="3">'
                    +comboBox+'</td>'
                +'</tr>'
        +'</table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="4"><a href="javascript:removeRow('
            +maxcount+')">Remove</a>').insertAfter("[id*=idForNewRow]:last");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your insert you have to use comboBox.domNode::

```
 $('<tr id="idForNewRow'+maxcount+'">'
    +'<td colspan="4">'
        +'<table id="idForBorder">'
            +'<tr class="even">'
                +'<th align="left"><font color="red">Design Abbr</font></th>'
                +'<td align="left" valign="bottom" colspan="3">'
                +comboBox.domNode+'</td>'
            +'</tr>'
    +'</table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="4"><a href="javascript:removeRow('
        +maxcount+')">Remove</a>').insertAfter("[id*=idForNewRow]:last");
```

Also if you are manually placing it on the page, you might as well take out the "stateSelect" from the new ComboBox contstructor.  that is where you place where you put the domid when you want the widget to place itself on the page.

Also instead of using the parser.parse command, you should just call the applications startup after its been inserted onto the page:: comboBox.startup()

EDIT(Above will not work because comboBox.domNode creates a node object)::
To make it more simple i would just reverse the order.  Add your html first then create the  widget, the widget then will be able to add itself to the page

```
    $('<tr id="idForNewRow' + maxcount + '">' + '<td colspan="4">' + 
      '<table id="idForBorder">' + 
      '<tr class="even">' + 
      '<th align="left"><font color="red">Design Abbr</font></th>' + 
      '<td align="left" valign="bottom" colspan="3" id="select' + maxcount + '"></td>'+
      '</tr>'+
    '</table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="4">'+
      '<a href="javascript: removeRow('+maxcount+')">Remove</a>').insertAfter("[id*=idForNewRow]:last");

    var stateStore = new Memory({data: [{name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
    {name:"Alaska", id:"AK"},
    {name:"Armed Forces the Americas", id:"AA"},
    {name:"California", id:"CA"},
    {name:"Connecticut ", id:"CT"}]});

    var comboBoxId = "solutionAbbr"+maxcount;
    var comboBox = new ComboBox({id: comboBoxId, name: "solutionAbbr",
    value: "California",store: stateStore,searchAttr: "name"}, "select"+maxcount);
    comboBox.startup();
```

As seen in http://jsfiddle.net/uLCS6/3/

Comment: Hi tik27, Thanks for your help. I inserted comboBox.domNode instead of comboBox. Now on clicking "Add Row" button when the new row comes it shows "[object HTMLDivElement]" (Earlier it was showing [Widget dijit.form.ComboBox, solutionAbbr1]"). Any Hint? Also as per your advise I have removed "stateSelect" from the new ComboBox contstructor. But at this point my main concern is to show this combobox when I am creating new row on the page. Currently in new dynamic row I am getting "[object HTMLDivElement]". Please check my code and let me know any solution for this. I am new to dojo

Comment: Check out the second part of the post i just added.  use this method instead it will be easier